# LinkedHashSet vs HashSet memory consumption

Tags: java

In Java how much more memory (bytes) is a LinkedHashSet consuming compared to a "normal" HashSet?
I know LinkedHashSet is slightly slower for certain operations, but what about memory usage?

Comment: Not seeing the dupe there @Bruno_Ferreira

Comment: Probably the cost of a couple of pointers and the list header. Did you check the implementation source on [GrepCode](http://grepcode.com)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer/blob/master/ElementCostInDataStructures.txt

A `HashSet` is ~32 bytes/element; a `LinkedHashSet` is ~40 bytes/element.

Comment: For 64-bit JDKs that's probably assuming `CompressedOops` is active, but that should be the case until you hit > 32GB heaps, on Hotspot at least.

Comment: You sure _should_ be using that, so yes, this should be the most realistic number for most scenarios.

Comment: Yeah, it's on by default, so most people are using it whether they know it or not. It _possible_ that someone who cares about the memory use of linked nodes is using a giant heap though.

Answer (score 2):

As the name suggests and the docs state explicitly, [`LinkedHashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), apart from the core [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), needs to maintain a linked list. I think it's safe to assume here that the upper bound of memory consumption can be approximated as if you'd have just two separate data structures: a hash set and a linked list. How much they consume memory, is a separate question.

However, if you need hard data on the number of bytes of memory used, you can always perform some tests on your own. It shouldn't be too hard to test, or google for a while - I'm sure there are already some test results available on the Internet.

**@edit, after Louis' answer**

It seemed interesting for me why the difference is smaller. Here's a simple benchmark I wrote:

```
package com.company;

import com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Creating data structures under test -------
        HashSet<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<>();

        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
        {
            hashSet.add(random.nextInt());
        }

        LinkedHashSet<Integer> linkedHashSet = new LinkedHashSet<>(hashSet);

        // Measuring memory usage --------------------
        long sizeOfHashSet = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(hashSet);
        long sizeOfLinkedHashSet = MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(linkedHashSet);
        System.out.println("Size of HashSet:\n" + sizeOfHashSet + " B");
        System.out.println("Size of LinkedHashSet:\n" + sizeOfLinkedHashSet + " B");
        System.out.println("LinkedHashSet is bigger from HashSet by " + (sizeOfLinkedHashSet*100/sizeOfHashSet - 100) + "%");

        System.out.println("\n");

        long numberOfElements = hashSet.size();
        System.out.println("Number of elements in the test HashSet: " + numberOfElements);

        System.out.println("Average size of a single element in HashSet: " + sizeOfHashSet/numberOfElements + " B");
        System.out.println("Average size of a single element in LinkedHashSet: " + sizeOfLinkedHashSet/numberOfElements + " B");
    }
}
```

After it running it several times I noticed it prints out fairy stable results (object sizes differ by +/- 2 KiB) which I present below:

```
Size of HashSet:
56347616 B
Size of LinkedHashSet:
64348040 B
LinkedHashSet is bigger from HashSet by 14%

Number of elements in the test HashSet: 999876
Average size of a single element in HashSet: 56 B
Average size of a single element in LinkedHashSet: 64 B
```

What's interesting, it doesn't align with values given by Louis. However, the difference in bytes per element is the same as Louis wrote (8 B). Could someone explain the discrepancy in values? Am I measuring object size in a wrong way?

Comment: `HashSet` is 32 bytes/element; `LinkedList` is 24 bytes/element, `LinkedHashSet` is 40 bytes/element.  They don't exactly just add.

Comment: there can be differences in running in a 32 bit versus 64 bit JVM, with or without `CompressedOops` on, and more.